# Retrieve list of values from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working with Python 2.7.

I have the following list:

```
mylist = [
       {u'id': 5650,
               u'children': [
                     {u'id': 4635},
                     {u'id': 5648}
                            ]},
       {u'id': 67,
               u'children': [
                     {u'id': 77}
                            ]}
      ]
```

I would like to retrieve the list of all children ids:

```
[4635, 5648, 77]
```

I have tried:

```
childrenids = [elem['children'][0]['id'] for elem in mylist]
```

but this only gives me the first one of each children:

```
[4635, 77]
```

I cannot manage to get all of them.

Any clue?

Comment: @PeterWood OP has list of dicts, so no duplicate keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`childrenids = [elem['children'][0]['id'] for elem in mylist]`

Why the `[0]`? This will only grab the value of the first child.

Instead try `childrenids = [child['id'] for elem in mylist for child in elem['children']]`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution iterates through the elements of the list (assuming that each element is a valid dictionary) and checks the type of each element based on the 'id' and 'children' naming convention.

```
def extract_id_values(mylist):
  ids_to_return_list = []

  for element in mylist:
      for key, value in element.items():
          if 'id' == key:
            ids_to_return_list.append(value)
          if 'children' == key:
            for children_elem in value:
              if 'id' in children_elem:
                ids_to_return_list.append(children_elem['id'])
  return ids_to_return_list
```